# How to remove two data points from a data set that have a large influence on the regression model

Tags: r, regression

I have found two outlier data points in my data set but I don't know how to remove them. All of the guides that I have found online seem to emphasize plotting the data but my question does not require plotting, it only takes regression model fitting. I am having great difficulty finding out how to remove the two data points from my data set and then fitting the new data set with a new model.
Here is the code that I have written and the outliers that I found:

```
library(alr4)
library(MASS)
data(lathe1)
head(lathe1)
y=lathe1$Life
x1=lathe1$Speed
x2=lathe1$Feed
x1_square=(x1)^2
x2_square=(x2)^2
#part A (Box-Cox method show log transformation)
y.regression=lm(y~x1+x2+(x1)^2+(x2)^2+(x1*x2))
mod=boxcox(y.regression, data=lathe1, lambda = seq(-1, 1, length=10))
best.lam=mod$x[which(mod$y==max(mod$y))]
best.lam
#part B (null-hypothesis F-test)
y.regression1_Reduced=lm(log(y)~1)
y.regression1=lm(log(y)~x1+x2+x1_square+x2_square+(x1*x2))
anova(y.regression1_Reduced, y.regression1)
#part D (F-test of log(Y) without beta1)
y.regression2=lm(log(y)~x2+x2_square)
anova(y.regression1_Reduced, y.regression2)
#part E (Cook's distance and refit)
cooks.distance(y.regression1)

Outliers:
9                10
0.7611370235     0.7088115474
```

Comment: You should provide a reproductible exemple of what you've done and where you have troubles, and read this post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266270/specific-warnings-to-newbies-about-homework-code-writing-please-debug-and-sscce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be able (if execution time / corpus size allows it) to pass through your data using a loop and copy / remove elems by your criteria to obtain your desired result e.g.

```py
corpus_list_without_outliers = []
for elem in corpus_list:
    if(elem.speed <= 10000) # elem.[any_param_name] < arbitrary_outlier_value
        # push to corpus_list_without_outliers because it is OK :)
print corpus_list_without_outliers
# regression algorithm after
```

this is how I'd see the situation, but you can change the above-if with a remove statement to avoid the creation of a second list etc. e.g.

```py
for elem in corpus_list:
    if(elem.speed > 10000) # elem.[any_param_name]
        # remove from current corpus because it is an outlier :(
print corpus_list
# regression algorithm after
```

Hope it helped you!

Comment: I forgot to respond to your solution when you posted it. It was very helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ManuelQuiroz I appreciate your feedback. I would like very much if you could also mind answering my question on my account about AST :). Thanks a lot.